# Devise Reset Password Link Redirecting to Homepage Only in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, devise

I'm having an issue with the devise reset password link (Rails 4). It is correctly sent, but when the user clicks the link, they are redirected to the homepage.

This **only** happens in production. It works perfect in development.

When the link it sent, it is in correct form, e.g:

```
http://website.com/d/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=gmf7ssHx4QRmUBdGb1nr
```

Running rake routes, everything tells me it should be pointing to the `PasswordsController` in devise:

```
new_user_password GET            /d/users/password/new(.:format)                                                             passwords#new
edit_user_password GET            /d/users/password/edit(.:format)                                                            passwords#edit
                   PATCH          /d/users/password(.:format)                                                                 passwords#update
                   PUT            /d/users/password(.:format)                                                                 passwords#update
```

I figure it must be some redirect happening in the [`PasswordsController`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb) of devise. There are only two places in the edit method a redirect would happen, `require_no_authentication` and `assert_reset_token_passed`. So I overwrite the edit methods with some puts and check the logs.

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController


  def require_no_authentication
    assert_is_devise_resource!
    return unless is_navigational_format?
    no_input = devise_mapping.no_input_strategies

    authenticated = if no_input.present?
      args = no_input.dup.push scope: resource_name
      warden.authenticate?(*args)
    else
      warden.authenticated?(resource_name)
    end

    if authenticated && resource = warden.user(resource_name)
      flash[:alert] = I18n.t("devise.failure.already_authenticated")
      puts "=========================="
      puts "APPARENTLY IM ALREADY AUTHENTICATED WTF?"
      puts "=========================="
      redirect_to after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    end
  end

  protected
   # Check if a reset_password_token is provided in the request
    def assert_reset_token_passed

      if params[:reset_password_token].blank?
        puts "reset_password_token is blank!!!"
        set_flash_message(:alert, :no_token)
        redirect_to new_session_path(resource_name)
      else
        puts "reset password token NOT blank"
      end

    end
end
```

Results in development: both put statements show up as expected.

Results in production: NO puts statements show up anywhere. In fact, when I check the live logs and go to the reset password link, it shows that it is directly going to the homepage:

```
2016-08-05T23:00:15.166276+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 177.227.42.66 at 2016-08-05 23:00:15 +0000
2016-08-05T23:00:15.168243+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PageController#index as HTML
```

I'm stumped on this one. How do the logs not show EITHER of those methods being called? I confirmed the deployment worked correctly and restarted heroku server.

Thanks!

Comment: Change the log level in production.rb if not done, `config.log_level = :debug`.

Comment: Already changed :/

Comment: Do you have a dns redirect happening? For example, is something redirecting you from website.com/d/users/... to www.website.com without the path?

Comment: Bingo. We have website.com forward to www.website.com, but apparently website.com/another-page.html also forwards to www.website.com. Please submit an answer and you will receive your bounty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a redirect happening before the request reaches your server that is dropping the path. For example, example.com/aboutus gets redirected to www.example.com without the '/aboutus'.

(Converted my comment above to an answer)